# Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 sudden random turn off

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, shutdown, overheating, debug

I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 with a LENOVO ThinkPad L13 Yoga.

Since a few days ago, Ubuntu randomly suddenly turns off. No Shut down just an immediate turn off. It looks like a power loss. It sometimes happens after 1 minute sometimes after a couple of hours.

I use Ubuntu alongside windows 10. This doesn't happen in windows.

**Edit:**

The last lines of `journalctl` show that the problem is overheating:

```
Jun 30 13:13:18 siavash-fra thermald[1184]: critical temp reached
Jun 30 13:13:19 siavash-fra wpa_supplicant[1190]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=270000
Jun 30 13:13:19 siavash-fra wpa_supplicant[1190]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=270000
Jun 30 13:13:19 siavash-fra thermald[1184]: critical temp reached
-- Reboot --
```

How can I find out what causes this overheating?

Comment: Did you look at system logs under `/var/log`  directory or the `journalctl` command?

Comment: Thanks for the great hint. The problem seems to be overheating. Here is the log from `journalctl` before the turn off:
`Jun 30 13:13:19 siavash-fra thermald[1184]: critical temp reached
-- Reboot --`

Comment: Overheating is a hardware problem. The question is unrelated to any OS.